# CSS provide spacing between different components

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I am trying to create a website which provides the status of each service.

something like this 
https://status.hipchat.com/

I don't have much experience with CSS, so I have tried to understand what I could using the chrome inspector and have created the following CSS. however, spacing doesn't quite look right.

1. Could someone let me know how could I fix?
2. is there any way I can optimize this?

```css
body {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

.legend {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}

.legend-item {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    font-size: .875rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #aaa;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.border-color {
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.component-container {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    -o-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1.1rem 1.25rem 1rem;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px
}

.name {
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 500;
    max-width: 75%;
}

.component-status {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    float: right;

}
.color-success {
    color: #36b37e;
}

.color-warning {
    color: #BCBE2A
}

.shared-partial.uptime-90-days-wrapper {
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.spacer {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0.75rem 1rem 0 1rem;
    height: 1px;
    background: #aaa;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-container border-color">
    <div class="shared-partial uptime-90-days-wrapper"><span class="name"> testing </span><br><span class="component-status color-success">Operational</span><svg
            height="34">
            <rect height="34" width="3" x="5" y="0" fill="#bcbe2a"></rect>
            <rect height="34" width="3" x="10" y="0" fill="#36b37e"></rect>
            <rect height="34" width="3" x="15" y="0" fill="#36b37e"></rect>
        </svg>
        <div class="legend">
            <div class="legend-item">90 days ago</div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="legend-item">96.67% uptime </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="legend-item">today</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what space? ...

Comment: If you want the same functionality as on your link, well, they re using SVG in your example.
Go for some JS library straight away, this stuff is hard, I have just recently used a library like this, I will try to find it

Comment: @TemaniAfif  padding around text.

Comment: @ptts I am actually using ReactJS to render this component.